# Muting Zoom While Listening to sth else

Tags: zoom-meeting

I have the following problem: When there is a Zoom-Meeting, I cannot unmute the app in order to be able to play other videos from the web. This is very annoying; does sb  have an idea on how to fix this? (I use the Zoom Desktop Client on Ubuntu 20.04.)

Comment: Quit the meeting or actually attend the meeting?

Comment: If you have an answer suggestion, please do not write a comment. Anyways, I do attend the meetings, but I want to listen to sth else.